# R function to find matches in two separate dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am new in the R programming so that I search a lot but cannot find exactly what I am looking for.

I have two dataframes like;

dataframe 1:

```
Accession `Gene Symbol`  `siCON-1` `siCON-2` `siCON-3` `siTR-1` `siTR-2` `siTR-3` `log2(siTR/s~   p_val `-log10(t.test si~
  <chr>     <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>             <dbl>   <dbl>              <dbl>
1 Q14258    TRIM25            2283.     2570.     2749.         489          498.         480.             -2.37  1.14e-4              3.94 
2 Q9P035    PTPLAD1; HACD3    1080.      857.     1060.         338.         439.         264              -1.52  1.74e-3              2.76 
3 Q9NP99    TREM1               45.7      NA        65.3         55           32.7          3.2            -0.873 3.10e-1              0.508
4 P35226    BMI1; COMMD3-~      46.3      42.6      36.1         12.3         23.7         12.6            -1.36  6.03e-3              2.22 
5 Q14117    DPYS                44.9      NA        73.1         51.7         36.9          0.8            -0.985 2.79e-1              0.554
6 Q6IAN0    DHRS7B             173.      149.      213.          92.3         73.7         62.6            -1.22  7.77e-3              2.11
```

dataframe 2:

```
      V1            V2                                                  V3                     V4  V5           V6
1 A0A075B6P5  R-HSA-109582  https://reactome.org/PathwayBrowser/#/R-HSA-109582             Hemostasis TAS Homo sapiens
2 A0A075B6P5 R-HSA-1280218 https://reactome.org/PathwayBrowser/#/R-HSA-1280218 Adaptive Immune System TAS Homo sapiens
3 A0A075B6P5 R-HSA-1280218 https://reactome.org/PathwayBrowser/#/R-HSA-1280218 Adaptive Immune System IEA Homo sapiens
4 A0A075B6P5 R-HSA-1643685 https://reactome.org/PathwayBrowser/#/R-HSA-1643685                Disease TAS Homo sapiens
5 A0A075B6P5 R-HSA-1643685 https://reactome.org/PathwayBrowser/#/R-HSA-1643685                Disease IEA Homo sapiens
6 A0A075B6P5  R-HSA-166658  https://reactome.org/PathwayBrowser/#/R-HSA-166658     Complement cascade TAS Homo sapiens
```

I just want to search each Accession ID from table 1 in table 2 and if it is matched, I would like to copy V2 and V4 from table 2 into table 1.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry for the confusion, Accession is the one for matching and V1 is the matching in the second dataframe.

I would like to compare 'Q14258' as an example from first dataframe in to second dataframe V1 and if there is a match, I would like to get V2 and V4 from second dataframe and add new column in the dataframe 1. I hope this clears it.

Edit2: I have used this code

`matches <- match(dataframe1$Accession,dataframe2$V1)`

and I can find the locations but I stuck at later.

```
 [1]  87059 130058 126612  50691  86417  97429  80338     NA     NA  34876 132613 138390  86681  48874     NA     NA     NA 121653     NA
  [20]  83210     NA     NA  22832  98354 104386  80531  11963    338     NA  58060  50032  12127 133036  11434 111307  26229     NA  89105
  [39] 107669   2329  57826     NA  12101  35659     NA 100915     NA 119519     NA     NA  92556 128938  13341 130104 133727 103605     NA
  [58] 105145 124370  27343     NA 100357  47092  93135  39138  66942     NA  23662 116234     NA  85757     NA 125647     NA     NA     NA
  [77]  59705     NA 109960  44700 135309 121942     NA  74508     NA     NA 111882  15365  94138 122808 137613  58407  28641     NA 110505
  [96]  76572     NA 104295     NA 130022  71937  63190 101249 113658 133776  36281     NA  61907  56843     NA  94265  24763 119085  81442
 [115]     NA     NA  89343     NA     NA 100597     NA   4782 131283  88704     NA     NA  67450  57507 118512  10851     NA  12182  58482
```

Comment: I don't see Accession ID in data frame 2.  Please supply the expected output from your sample data and explain how to identify a match.

Comment: Thank @Limey, I would like to compare 'Q14258' as an example from first dataframe in to second dataframe V1 and if there is a match, I would like to get V2 and V4 from second dataframe and add new column in the dataframe 1. I hope this clears it. Thanks

Comment: `Q14258` does not appear anywhere in data frame 2, so no matching is possible.

Comment: Thanks @Limey i havent put all the data here it was top of the dataframe which composed of about 600k of data. Could let me know how you search for it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to combine two dataframes then you want to use a `join`.

I made some example data because I am not sure I understand your data in the question. I understand that `Accession`in df1 is the same as `V1`in df2.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tribble(
    ~Accession, ~GeneSymbol,
        'Q1', 'TRIM25',
        'Q2', 'PTPLAD1',
        'Q3', 'TREM1' )
df2 <- tribble(
    ~V1, ~V2,
    'Q1', 'R-HSA-109581',
    'Q2', 'R-HSA-109582',
    'Q4', 'R-HSA-109583',
    'Q5', 'R-HSA-109584',
    'Q6', 'R-HSA-109585' )
)
```

How you make the join depends on what you want. With an `inner_join()` the result contains keys (`Accession`) that are in both df1 and df2.

[image: inner join]

```
df1 %>% 
    inner_join(df2, by=c("Accession" = "V1"))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>   Accession GeneSymbol V2          
>   <chr>     <chr>      <chr>       
> 1 Q1        TRIM25     R-HSA-109581
> 2 Q2        PTPLAD1    R-HSA-109582
> ```

`left_join()` keeps all the keys in df1 (`Accession`) and adds columns from df2 that had matching keys. It puts NA for the new columns for the keys in df1 without a match in df2.

```
df1 %>% 
    left_join(df2, by=c("Accession" = "V1"))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>   Accession GeneSymbol V2          
>   <chr>     <chr>      <chr>       
> 1 Q1        TRIM25     R-HSA-109581
> 2 Q2        PTPLAD1    R-HSA-109582
> 3 Q3        TREM1      NA
> ```

There are other also kinds of joins. Check out the information in Hadley Wickham's book [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Aaron, this is a great explanation. And also thank you for providing R book for me. I definitely go into it with more details.

Comment: No problem. Would you kindly accept the answer if it solved your problem?